# Tail.Select plugin render the li tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tail.select

I'm using https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select plugin to create my Combobox/Dropdowns. Everything works fine, but I'd like to change the HTML of the rendered `<li>` tags (both in the dropdown and in the labels list).

You can see the plugin in action in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs95d183/)**.

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/wiki/Events-Callbacks) there is a callback named `cbLoopItem` which says:

> You can hook your own function to the cbLoopItem option to intervene
>   or take over the render process for each single option. Your own
>   function receives 4 parameters:
>
> - `item` The current `item` object, which should get rendered
> - `optgroup` The current "group" / "parent" Element
> - `search` The search string (if it is a search), undefined otherwise
> - `root` The root "dropdown-inner" object.
>
> Your own function SHOULD return an Element object, which gets added to
>   the dropdown list, but you can also return null to skip this single
>   option and false to break the render process.
>
> **Please Note**
>
> - You MUST return an `<li>` Element, if you're don't manipulate cbLoopGroup too!
> - You MUST NOT add the global data-key or data-group attributes!
> - You MUST NOT add a click event handler!

So it seems I could use this callback to render my `<li>`. Currently, the plugin creates the following HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown-option" data-key="1" data-group="Header one">Value 1</li>
```

And I want the result to be something like:

```
<li class="dropdown-option some-class-i-can-add" data-key="1" data-group="Header one">
    <i class="fab fa-amazon"></i> Value 1
</li>
```

I tried without success:

```
tail.select('#my-select',
{
    // ...
    cbLoopItem: function(item, optgroup, search, root)
    {
        var x =  $('<li>Testing first without icon</li>');

        return x;
    }
});
```

But it returns the error `Uncaught TypeError: h.setAttribute is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

The documentation says "You MUST return an `<li>` Element (...)" and I was returning either only plain string or a jQuery object.

To solve this, the `<li>` must be created using the `document.createElement` javascript function.

```
tail.select('#my-select',
{
    cbLoopItem: function(item, optgroup, search, root)
    {
        var icon = '<i class="fab fa-amazon"></i>';
        var newItem = document.createElement('li');

        newItem.innerHTML = icon + item.value; // will create '<li><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i> Value 1</li>'

        return newItem;
    },
});
```

This only works for the items in the dropdown list. The labels container do not receive the `<i/>` icon, which means I need to use the callback `cbComplete` and the event `change` in order to achieve the final goal: always show an icon no matter if in the labels container or in the dropdown.

The `cbComplete` is necessary because there might be already options selected (when the plugin is initialized) and I wanted to show the icon immediatelly.

```
cbComplete: function(item)
{
    var labels = $(item).find('.select-handle');

    // might be null (none selected)
    if (!labels)
        return;

    var icon = '<i class="fab fa-amazon"></i>';

    $.each(labels, function(i, label)
    {
        var key         = $(label).attr('data-key');
        var text        = $(label).text();
        var originalLi  = $(item).find('.dropdown-inner').find('[data-key="' + key + '"]'); // must always exists

        $(label).html(icon + text);
    });
}
```

The `change` event is fired everytime an option is selected into the labels container:

```
tail.select('#my-select',
{
    //
}).on('change', function(item, state)
{
    // No need to do anything
    if (state == 'unselect')
        return;

    var labels = $(this.container).find('.select-handle');
    var dropdown = $(this.dropdown);

    // might be null (none selected)
    if (!labels)
        return;

    var icon = '<i class="fab fa-amazon"></i>';

    $.each(labels, function(i, label)
    {
        var key         = $(label).attr('data-key');
        var text        = $(label).text();
        var originalLi  = $(dropdown).find('.dropdown-inner').find('[data-key="' + key + '"]'); // must always exists

        $(label).html(icon + text);
    });
));
```

I wanted an icon, but you can use an image or anything else.

You can see the final result in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7z91gej/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The old tail.select repository is gone completely, and the new version is here -

https://github.com/wolffe/tail.select.js

Also, the demo is available here -

https://getbutterfly.com/tail-select/

Since the plugin has disappeared, a few years ago, I have updated it to version 0.5.22 and an ES6 version 0.6 is in the works. I am maintaining this plugin/library full time.